# JavaScript content and curl content parsing

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I try to load a page with curl to work with the sourcode.

Now i do the following thinks

```
// curl handle
$curl = curl_init('https://www.example.de/page.html');

// curl options
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);

// catch sourcecode     
$content = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);     

// make a dom-object
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom-> loadHTML($content);
#$dom-> loadHTMLFile($content);


$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
```

As result i get not the hole sourcecode, only the javascript part of the website before this generate the main html-sourcecode.

If i `print_r($content)` i will see the correct copy of the website url.

Maybe this output can help "`DOMXPath Object ( [document] => (object value omitted) )` " - In Mainresult it makes no different if i use `loadHTML` or `loadHTMLFile` both wont generate a workable dom-object.

What i did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As result i get not the hole sourcecode, only the javascript part of the website before this generate the main html-sourcecode.

So it seams that you are requesting a website which is mainly driven by JS and does not include the resulting HTML/DOM within the markup. PHP cannot »execute« the website, what includes running the Javascript such that the DOM will be generated. You can try to use a headless Browser like Phantom to run the page and extract the resulting HTML from there. But I guess that wont give you the result you are looking for, f.i.: Event Listeners attached by the JS wont work if you just export the markup. Additionally, when delivered to client, the JS will run again, what might result in unexpected things like duplicated content etc.

Comment: is there another way to get the sourcecode for this kind of gernerated websites?

Comment: AFIK not. Since it is the JS that generates the DOM/HTML and not the server, you need to run it to gain it. With curl/php you can download the JS source and all connected Assets of the page, basically everything that is linked within the page. Everything that is generated wont be accessible without running the JS